# Inserting new value into multiple node instances

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, rdl, xquery-sql

I am trying to update a SSRS report XML so that every single report parameter has the `<Hidden>true</Hidden>` value set on it. Some parameters will already have the value and can be skipped. In theory if that value is set to false in the designer, instead of `<Hidden>false</Hidden>`, it just doesn't include the node all together, but I'd prefer to look for and replace any instances of that just to be sure.

The problem I am having is that a given report can have X amount of Report Parameters on it. All attempts I have done to use XML.modify only works on the first parameter. Is there some way I can do this update to all instances of ReportParameter?

This is an example of some truncated rdl code that just has the parameters on it:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="FederalEmployerIdentificationKey">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <Prompt>Federal Employer Identification</Prompt>
      <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
    </ReportParameter>
   <ReportParameter Name="ThirdPartySickPayAddedToOASDIWages">
      <DataType>Float</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <Prompt>3rd Party Sick Pay Added To Social Security Wages</Prompt>
      <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="ShortDateFormat">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>
</Report>
```

The first parameter has no `<Hidden>` node at all, the second has `<Hidden>false</Hidden>`, and the third `<Hidden>true</Hidden>`. So the first would need an insert, the second an update (or delete and then insert), and the third doesn't need anything done to it.

These are the updates I have tried so far. They do replace/insert as told, but only on the first instance of a `<ReportParameter>`.

```
    --Replace Hidden false with Hidden true, if it is found
    UPDATE @xmlTable
    SET ContentXml.modify('
        replace value of 
        (/*:Report/*:ReportParameters/*:ReportParameter[*:Hidden="false"]
        /*:Hidden/text())[1] 
        with "true"
    ')
    WHERE ContentXml.exist('/*:Report/*:ReportParameters/*:ReportParameter[*:Hidden="false"]')=1;

    --Insert Hidden true if no Hidden is found
    UPDATE @xmlTable
    SET ContentXml.modify('
        insert 
        (<Hidden>true</Hidden>)
        as last 
        into (//*:ReportParameters/*:ReportParameter)[1]
    ')
    WHERE ContentXml.exist('(/*:Report/*:ReportParameters/*:ReportParameter/*:Hidden)')=0;
```

From what I can see in researching this, these modify functions only work on one node at a time... but I have to believe there are ways to do this in these circumstances... I think I might just not know the correct terminology to Google with.

Comment: Youre research is pretty much correct, one of the annoyances of SQL Server's XML.modify() method is that it can only modify a single value at a time. While it's certainly possible to do this with XML.modify() it would require some looping/cursor logic instead of a set-based statement like you'd use for everything-not-XML. Have you considered using an external process instead, such as a PowerShell script, to make the modifications?

Comment: Aside... wildcard namespaces are somewhat slow and can cause you to select/modify incorrect elements from unintended namespaces. If you don't want to declare namespaces inside your XPath you can prepend your T-SQL statements with something similar to `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition') ...`

Comment: Thanks AlwaysLearning. I actually just wrapped my mind around including the namespace declaration, and started to put it in my other scripts to be more direct. I got a bit lazy with this one but I do plan to implement it. I hadn't considered a Powershell script for any of this, but I see below someone posted one that might work out for us, I will certainly look into it more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following approach.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ContentXml XML);
INSERT @tbl (ContentXml) VALUES
(N'<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="FederalEmployerIdentificationKey">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <Prompt>Federal Employer Identification</Prompt>
      <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
    </ReportParameter>
   <ReportParameter Name="ThirdPartySickPayAddedToOASDIWages">
      <DataType>Float</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <Prompt>3rd Party Sick Pay Added To Social Security Wages</Prompt>
      <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="ShortDateFormat">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>
</Report>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @UPDATE_STATUS BIT = 1;
    
WHILE @UPDATE_STATUS > 0 
BEGIN
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'
        , 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd)
    UPDATE t
    SET ContentXml.modify('replace value of 
        (/Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter[Hidden="false"]/Hidden/text())[1] 
        with "true"')
    FROM @tbl AS t
    WHERE ContentXml.exist('/Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter[Hidden="false"]')=1;
        
    SET @UPDATE_STATUS = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;


SET @UPDATE_STATUS = 1;
    
WHILE @UPDATE_STATUS > 0
BEGIN
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'
        , 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd)
    UPDATE @tbl
    SET ContentXml.modify('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition";
        insert 
        <Hidden>true</Hidden>
        as last 
        into (/Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter[not(Hidden)])[1]
    ')
    --WHERE ContentXml.exist('(/Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter/Hidden)')=0;
    WHERE ContentXml.exist('(/Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter[not(Hidden)])')=1;
        
    SET @UPDATE_STATUS = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;

 -- after
 SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output XML**

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="FederalEmployerIdentificationKey">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <Prompt>Federal Employer Identification</Prompt>
      <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="ThirdPartySickPayAddedToOASDIWages">
      <DataType>Float</DataType>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <Prompt>3rd Party Sick Pay Added To Social Security Wages</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="ShortDateFormat">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
</Report>
```

Comment: In T-SQL the `;` character is a statement terminator, not a statement begininator. i.e.: `;WITH ...` is a code smell.

Comment: Thank you Yitzhak Khabinsky for the suggestion. I did end up trying something very similar to this approach and while it seems to work, I just don't know how well it will hold up when I iterate through nearly 300 reports, all with multiple parameters. My version did involve a temp table though which yours avoids, so maybe yours is the better approach, I'll give it a go. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this and while the replace part of it works great, the insert is not working at all on any parameters that have no Hidden nodes in them yet. I believe it has something to do with my .exist statement. Can anyone validate what that should look like? This is what it currently is set to, as per my OP above...which I though was working but apparently not... ```WHERE ContentXml.exist('(/Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter/Hidden)')=0;```

Comment: @svenGUTT, unfortunately, MS SQL Server XQuery implementation is not fully standards compliant. That's why your task is not so straight forward. Please up-vote my suggestion to Microsoft: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0 The comments section is very interesting to read too.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a powershell script that will work

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"


$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()

$parameters = $doc.Descendants($ns + "ReportParameter")

foreach($parameter in $parameters)
{
 
   $hidden = $parameter.Element($ns + "Hidden")
   if($hidden -eq $null)
   {
      $parameter.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::get('Hidden'),'true'))
   }
   else
   {
      $hidden.SetValue('true')
   }
}
$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I hadn't even considered trying to use Powershell for this (mainly because I am not much of a PS user). Ultimately, we do need to export all these reports so we can load them into PowerBI, so this might be a good approach to work into the SSIS project that extracts our rdls. I'll give it a try...thank you!

Comment: You can use Invoke-SQL to query and insert into database : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Comment: Cool, I will check that out, might save some steps. Quick FUP question on namespace referencing. I want to expand your script to possibly update the DataSource node details too. Some of the nodes use a namespace identifier, ie ```<rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>```. I figured out how to get down to the node, but I keep getting empty values for those types. If I manually remove the rd: references from the node in the source xml, it works. How can I reference those types of nodes? I currently am using ```$securityType = $dataSource.Descendants($ns + "SecurityType").Value```.

Comment: Please ignore the above...I was able to find I had to add an additional call to the rd namespace prefix, and reference that in my descendants call  ```$rd = $doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("rd");``` for getting the prefix, and ```$securityType = $dataSource.Descendants($rd + "SecurityType").Value``` to use it.